# Check if App is started with GameCenter challenge

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I would really like to get help of you, because i am at this problem for around 2 weeks now, and i could not even find something that would help me a bit.

If i get a challenge for my app and click on it, my app will open.
Is there a way to get the information on what challenge i clicked and let me display e.g. the score that i have to beat inside my game?

I tried getting the Arguments that the app is started with, but there is nothing that looks like challenge related data in there.

I already managed to get all the challenges for my game, but there is now way i can tell which one i clicked on with that method.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing, when you click the notification or open the game via the game center, no useful information is passed to your game.

All I have found are hacky solutions, like putting descriptive text (maybe the requestor's name) in the invite text and then showing that same text when displaying the list of available matches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thats very sad to hear. I don't think i will get it to work the way i wanted it to be. Hopefully apple with implement something like that in the future.